# Why does $\cos(n \pi)=1$ if $n$ is even, but $\cos(n\pi) = -1$ if $n$ is odd?

Tags: trigonometry

I am taking Calculus 1 after graduating college several years ago. I have forgotten a good amount of info and am having difficulty searching info for this on my own.

Here is what is causing me confusion:

$\cos{n\pi}=1$ (if $n$ is even)

$\cos{n\pi}=-1$ (if $n$ is odd)

I am seeking an explanation as to why this is. From what I've gathered so far it has to do with radians and trigonometric functions, but the info is very unclear to me.

Comment: What is $\cos0$? What is $\cos\pi$? Now use the fact that $\cos$ has period $2\pi$.

Comment: It in essence comes down to: If you turn 180 degrees, then you'll be facing the opposite direction. If you do two 180 degree turns, you'll be facing your original direction. And then so on for three, four, five, etc.

Comment: Are you familiar with the [unit circle](https://www.mathsisfun.com/geometry/unit-circle.html) ?

Comment: @PM2 Ring - I am planning time tomorrow to go over the unit circle again. I studied it at one point, but completely forgot about it after this many years away.

Answer (score 4):

Your question seems to show some confusion about the definition of sine and cosine.

[image]

We have a circle of radius 1.  Starting at the rightmost point on the circle coordinate (1,0) you proceed to travel around the circle in the counter-clockwise direction $x$ units.  The coordinates of the point at the end of this arc is $(\cos x, \sin x).$  This should be your definition of sine and cosine.  It is a more useful definition than anything based off of right triangles.  There are other ways to define the functions based on complex exponentials, but you are not ready for that.

Suppose you travel exactly half-way around.  How far have you traveled?  The circumference of the circle is $2\pi$ units.  You have covered a half a circle, so you have traveled $\pi$ units.  What are the coordinates of the point half way from the starting point?  $(-1,0)$

$\cos \pi = -1, \sin \pi = 0$

Suppose you travel a full rotation.  You have traveled $2\pi$ units, and you are back at your starting point.

$\cos 2\pi = 1, \sin \pi = 0$

You can make multiple full rotations around your circle, pass go, and continue to your destination.

For any $x, \cos (x+2\pi) = \cos x, \sin (x+2\pi) = \sin x$

I hope this helps, and helps to trigger some memories from pre-calculus.

Answer (score 0):

You have to notice that, being $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, then
$$\cos (x) = \cos (x+2k\pi),$$
(this is because the $\cos x$ fuction has period $2\pi$) so from this it's clear that $\cos(n\pi)=\cos(n\pi+2k\pi)=\cos((n+2k)\pi)$ for all $n,k\in\mathbb{Z}$, and this means that all even values of $n$ will give you the same value (and all odd number will aso give the same value), since $n+2k$ is even if and only if $n$ is even (respectively for $n$ odd). So you conclude that
$$\text{$n$ even: }\ \cos(n\pi)=\cos(0\cdot\pi)=\cos(0)=1$$
$$\text{$n$ odd: }\ \cos(n\pi)=\cos(1\cdot\pi)=\cos(1)=-1$$

Comment: Or just plot it.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I know, but considering the question seemed to have some issues with the properties of sine and cosine I considered this is way more helpful to a better understanding of the concept, since the plotting isn't a real mathematical proof (though it may be useful to check results). Thanks for your comment!

Comment: I don't think one needs to *prove* a solution to answer the "why" question.